# EJS if statement doesn´t works

Tags: node.js, ejs

I´m novice in web development and I´ve been learning some nodejs stuff as well as ejs in the last couple days. I have been faced a issue regarding  if statement at ejs. When I try compare disciplina.id with value obtained from element this bunch of code doesn´t work properly, but if I compare to a number, it works well. The error shows the "el" variable as not define, but console.log() prints the value from selected element. Is there some tip about if statement in Ejs? Some reason for it?

```
<script>
                function addOnComboList() 
                {
                    var el = document.getElementById("listaDisciplina");
                    var tabela = document.getElementById("itensSelecionados");
                    var row = tabela.insertRow(1);
                    var cellNome = row.insertCell(0);
                    var cellAula = row.insertCell(1);
                    var cellRelogio = row.insertCell(2);
                    var cellTipo = row.insertCell(3);
                    var cellOpcao = row.insertCell(4);

                    console.log(el.value);

                 <% disciplinas.forEach(disciplina => { %>
                    <% if (el.value === disciplina.id) { %>
                            cellNome.innerHTML = "<%= disciplina.nome %>";
                            cellAula.innerHTML = "<%= disciplina.cargaHorariaAula %>";
                            cellRelogio.innerHTML = "<%= disciplina.cargaHorariaRelogio %>";
                            cellTipo.innerHTML = "<%= disciplina.tipo %>";
                            cellOpcao.innerHTML = "<a class='btn btn-danger' href=''>Deletar</a>";
                    <% } %>
                    
                 <% }); %>

                        


                }
            </script>
```

Error printed:

```
ReferenceError: C:\planoapp\views\planotrabalho\create.ejs:121
    119| 

    120|                  <% disciplinas.forEach(disciplina => { %>

 >> 121|                     <% if (el.value == disciplina.id) { %>

    122|                             cellNome.innerHTML = "<%= disciplina.nome %>";

    123|                             cellAula.innerHTML = "<%= disciplina.cargaHorariaAula %>";

    124|                             cellRelogio.innerHTML = "<%= disciplina.cargaHorariaRelogio %>";


el is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (C:\planoapp\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:662:12), <anonymous>:46:8)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
supressed stack trace
```

Answer (score 1):

EJS not allows compare local variables to EJS´s variable. I made a copy of content from EJS array to a new local array. Thus, I could compare it.